# Texto aparece fuera del modal bootstrap

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, modal

Amigos, alguien me puede ayudar con este problema? Tengo un modal, que contiene una tabla con varias celdas, y una de las celdas contiene un texto largo, pero el texto sale fuera del modal no respetando la celda.
Adjunto imagen para referencia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien puede saber porque sucede esto?

---

El codigo y las clases son las siguiente:

```
<!-- MODAL DE INFORMACION PROCESOS -->
<div class="modal fade" id="verProcesoModal" role="dialog" data-keyboard="false">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header"><h5 class="title" id="varCodigoProceso"></h5></div>
        <!-- MODAL BODY -->
        <div class="modal-body">
            <label>Detalles del proceso realizado:</label>
            <div id="varProcesoTecnico2">

            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="table-layout:fixed">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="250px">Fecha del proceso:</td>
                        <td class="text-primary"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Técnico del proceso:</td>
                        <td class="text-primary">Juan Lopez</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>¿Que Software o Drivers instaló?:</td>
                        <td class="text-primary">SISTEMA OPERATIVO + DRIVERS + SOFTWARE
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Observaciones del Proceso:</td>
                        <td>EL AJAX ES SIMPLEMENTE "SERIALIZAR" EL FORMULARIO, Y EN EL CONTROLADOR SIMPLEMENTE RECIBES LOS DATOS Y LOS SEPARAS, REVISA LA DOCUMENTACIóN, REALMENTE ES MUY SENCILLO.</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Costo del proceso:</td>
                        <td class="text-primary"> $ 5000</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- FIN MODAL BODY -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar Proceso</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Muchas Gracias

Comment: Acabo de probar tu codigo y funciona bien.  Talvez estas poniendo `width` al modal en algun lugar.

Comment: Hola Alan, al abrir el modal, el texto sale fuera del modal, te sucede lo mismo? Ya probe con un width pero no lo respeta.

Comment: Hola, yo también lo acabo de probar y funciona a la perfección. Mira demo =>  https://jsbin.com/govahixiqa/edit?html,output

Comment: A mi me sale bien.  Remueve todo el css que tengas afectando a `verProcesoModal` incluyendo width a ver si funciona.

Comment: Hola Alan, verProcesoModal no tiene ningún css, si lo pruebo en el jsbin funciona bien pero si lo coloco en mi proyecto no. Al parecer el problema esta en la Tabla, que clase se le podria poner para que respete el ancho? ç

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trate de emular tu situacion colocando el texto todo pegado para que hiciera el mismo efecto así:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- MODAL DE INFORMACION PROCESOS -->
<div class="modal fade" id="verProcesoModal" role="dialog" data-keyboard="false">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header"><h5 class="title" id="varCodigoProceso"></h5></div>
        <!-- MODAL BODY -->
        <div class="modal-body">
            <label>Detalles del proceso realizado:</label>
            <div id="varProcesoTecnico2">

            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="table-layout:fixed">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="250px">Fecha del proceso:</td>
                        <td class="text-primary"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Técnico del proceso:</td>
                        <td class="text-primary">Juan Lopez</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>¿Que Software o Drivers instaló?:</td>
                        <td class="text-primary">SISTEMA OPERATIVO + DRIVERS + SOFTWARE
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Observaciones del Proceso:</td>
                        <td>ELAJAXESSIMPLEMENTE"SERIALIZAR"ELFORMULARIO,YENEL CONTROLADORSIMPLEMENTERECIBESLOSDATOSYLOSSEPARAS,REVISALADOCUMENTACIóN,REALMENTEESMUYSENCILLO.</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Costo del proceso:</td>
                        <td class="text-primary"> $ 5000</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- FIN MODAL BODY -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar Proceso</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#verProcesoModal">
  Ver Modal
</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Ahora bien para arreglarlo coloque una propiedad css que muy seguramente te puede servir el cual es `word-break: break-all;`, intenta colocarlo así en tu código:

```
#verProcesoModal table td{
  word-break: break-all !important;
}
```

**Ejemplo funcional:**

```css
#verProcesoModal table td{
  word-break: break-all !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- MODAL DE INFORMACION PROCESOS -->
<div class="modal fade" id="verProcesoModal" role="dialog" data-keyboard="false">
 <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header"><h5 class="title" id="varCodigoProceso"></h5></div>
        <!-- MODAL BODY -->
        <div class="modal-body">
            <label>Detalles del proceso realizado:</label>
            <div id="varProcesoTecnico2">

            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="table-layout:fixed">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="250px">Fecha del proceso:</td>
                        <td class="text-primary"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Técnico del proceso:</td>
                        <td class="text-primary">Juan Lopez</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>¿Que Software o Drivers instaló?:</td>
                        <td class="text-primary">SISTEMA OPERATIVO + DRIVERS + SOFTWARE
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Observaciones del Proceso:</td>
                        <td>ELAJAXESSIMPLEMENTE"SERIALIZAR"ELFORMULARIO,YEN EL CONTROLADORSIMPLEMENTERECIBESLOSDATOSYLOSSEPARAS,REVISALADOCUMENTACIóN,REALMENTEESMUYSENCILLO.</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Costo del proceso:</td>
                        <td class="text-primary"> $ 5000</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- FIN MODAL BODY -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar Proceso</button>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#verProcesoModal">
  Ver Modal
</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

NO estoy diciendo que tu texto este junto como yo lo force, pero seguro hay algún css que evita que respete su celda, por eso force este efecto para que te puedas guiar y ojala sea la respuesta a tu problema.

Comment: Me funciono correctamente, agradezco mucho tu ayuda David. Saludos